# Visual Studio 2015 references warning issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, tfs, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I recently upgraded an old `ASP.Net MVC3` project that was storing all our COTS (commercial off-the-shelf) .DLL files in source control to use NuGet Restore Packages instead.

Now whenever someone gets the source afresh from TFS (Team Foundation Server), the references I updated to NuGet Packages all have the warning icon on them. Neither building nor cleaning and rebuilding fix the references.

If I click any NuGet reference in a project, the references all appear to update. The warning icons disappear and the references seem to be fine. The project builds without sissue.

This has to be done for each project in the solution, though once done once it is fine and doesn't reoccur. But this is slowing down new employees and is cumbersome.

Does anyone know of something I might have missed?

The `.ddl` files are for packages like `MVC, StructureMap, Log4Net ect`

I have searched (via Google) and the only related question is one showing `NuGet` packages having a different icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Restore Nuget Packages` option from the Solution Explorer by right clicking on the solution:

[image]

You can also configure Nuget Restore to run on build from the Nuget Manager Settings windows:

[image]

Comment: The restore NuGet Packages run but the References still show the warning Icon. And I'll check that auto is checked and get back to you, thanks for looking.